# Why aren't my font-weight and letter-spacing working outside h1?

Tags: html, css

very new to this and have tried several fixes without success.

Inside h1, my fonts are all correct and reacting as expected:

```
h1 {
position:relative;
left: -10px;
top: -16px;
padding: 2em;
height: 3em;
width: 100%;
background: #545454;
font-family: "Avenir Light", sans-serif;
font-size: .7em;
text-align: center;
color: darkgray}
```

```
h1 p {
    font-weight: 30;
    word-spacing: 30px;}
```

But the text isn't responding *anywhere* else on my page, even when inserted under body, body p, into each individual element... It's driving me nuts!

```
body {
    margin: 0, 0;
    padding: 0, 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    background: #765264;
    color: white;
    font-family: "Avenir Light", sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1.5;
}


body p {
    font-size: 1em;
    font-family: "Century Gothic";
    font-weight: 30;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}
```

Weirdly, inserting letter-spacing above seemed to make the spacing larger.

Here's my HTML, for reference:

````
    <head>
        <div class="header" id="myHeader">
        <h1>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="peytonsite.css">
        <p>
        <img src="https://static.wixstatic.com/media/058e45_e590acfd22c440f4b5c89450738f321d~mv2.png/v1/fill/w_100,h_100,al_c,q_85,usm_0.66_1.00_0.01/058e45_e590acfd22c440f4b5c89450738f321d~mv2.webp">

            <a>HOME</a>
            <a>SKILLS</a>
            <a>PORTFOLIO</a>
            <a>EXPERIANCE</a>
            <a>CONTACT</a>

        </p>
        </h1>
        </div>
    </head>

    <article>

        <section id="LANDING">
            <img id="LongLogo" src="https://static.wixstatic.com/media/058e45_0291502c1e424532bbd24f9cfd50fd1e~mv2.png/v1/fill/w_1466,h_348,al_c,q_90,usm_0.66_1.00_0.01/Long%20Logo.webp">

            <p>PASSIONATE DESIGN</p>```

Please help!
````

Comment: You can't put paragraphs inside headings. It's invalid HTML.

Comment: Could you also provide us with your html, to see the structure?

Comment: I added HTML to my original post!

Answer (score 2):

Update:
`30` isn't a valid font-weight, and, your font may not necessarily have a boldness available to it.

Try: `font-weight: bold;`
or: `font-weight: 300;`  (300 is usually non-bold)

A few other ideas:
You probably want a comma between `h1 p {` in your second CSS block.

Secondly-  Is your target text within a `<p>` block?

For debugging purposes, what happens if you append `!important` to your styles?  Does that show what you want?

What happens if you delete the `h1 p { ...` block, and add this in at the bottom of your CSS?

```
   p {
    font-weight: 300!important;
    word-spacing: 30px!important;}
```

If nothing changes, I suspect you don't have the right CSS selectors.

[Here is a CodePen of your CSS correctly applying](https://codepen.io/eleanor/pen/rNVNLOK)